# What's the difference between referencing a method as an array versus a string?

Tags: php, syntax

As an example, let's use the `is_callable()` function which accepts takes a function name as an argument and checks whether or not it can be successfully called from that point in the code.

If I want to check if an object's method is callable, it seems like I have two choices when referencing a static method:

Option 1:

```
 is_callable(array("ObjectName", "MethodName"));
```

Option 2:

```
 is_callable("ObjectName::MethodName");
```

(Instance methods can seemingly only be checked using Option 1, passing an object instance as the first array value rather than the string containing the class name.)

Is this just a matter of preference, or syntactic sugar, or is there a solid difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just syntactic sugar - `is_callable("ObjectName::MethodName")` looks much nicer, but requires a higher PHP version than the array method.

However, to create a "pointer" to an *instance* method you *must* use `array($instance, 'MethodName')`.

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback):

```
// Type 4: Static class method call (As of PHP 5.2.3)
call_user_func('MyClass::myCallbackMethod');
```

Comment: I thought as much, but it's nice to have it confirmed. Thanks.